# showing all recent posts in theme

Tags: theme-development, themes, recent-posts

I am creating a wp theme & I stuck at one point.

I have recent post listing on my home page of theme which have `See All` link which redirect user to the page which list all the recent posts except news category.

[image]

So my question is what will be the link of `See All` on my home page ? 
can we create a new page at time of applying theme & link to it or there is any better option ?

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what exactly theme is for - your own site? Sites? Public release?

There isn't really simple and clean way to package functionally unique page with theme to appear at specific custom URL. The path of least resistance tends to be to include page template with theme and instruct users to create a page and assign that template to it to achieve functionality.

Most of other solutions are either unreasonably complex (and as such tend to be considered *plugin territory*) or might rub users wrong way (such as automatically adding pages they didn't ask for to their site).